# Is suborbital point-to-point flight on the SpaceShipTwo possible?

Tags: sub-orbital, spaceplane, virgin-galactic

As of until now, both the SpaceShipTwo and its retired predecessor the SpaceShipOne, landed on the same spaceport they launched from in their spaceflights, the Mojave air- and spaceport. I wonder whether there are spaceports in America that are close enough so the SpaceShipTwo could reach the other one when launching from another. Or whether the SpaceShipOne could have done it (it could reach a higher apogee than VSS Unity is able to). The Edwards Air Force Base is very close to the Mojave spaceport. Reportedly 17 mi (27 km) though in my source I'm unsure whether it was the airport I meant. Vandenberg is not that far from these airports either.

Would the Scaled Composites spaceplanes be able to reach another spaceport or military base through spaceflight? If so, which ones, and is such flight going to be tested?

Comment: Why restrict yourself to spaceports at all? It takes off tied to a plane, and it lands like a plane, so any airport should do, no? I think the "biggest" problem is going to be the front skid which not every airport owner might want scraping across their runways.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think these spaceplanes need a long runway for a safe landing. The Space Shuttle and the Concorde could land on certain airports only (and the Space Shuttle needed a parachute to decelerate in time). SpaceShipOne and Two are faster than the Concorde. I don't understand your 2nd statement. What's a skid? The planes use gears.

Comment: SpaceShipTwo has wheels on the main landing gear but a skid on the nose.

Comment: @JörgWMittag A what?

Comment: Here is a question about Dream Chaser's nose gear skid, with some photos: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45692/3721

Comment: @JörgWMittag I didn't even know that the SpaceShipTwo has such thing. I thought it has a nose gear.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "point to point".  Beyond the airport logistics issues, the question is how much cross-range are you likely to get out of SS2.  Given its short flight duration probably not much.  No SFO to Tokyo, SFO to LAX likely doable, LAX to NYC probably unlikely. (wild guesses on my part).

Comment: Note that the shuttle drag chute was not implemented until the 47th mission.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Wow, you're right! I didn't know that either. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPexsehcMhw

Comment: @CarlosN I provided examples: Mojave to Edwards or Mojave to Vandenberg or Edwards to Vandenberg. Whether that would be doable by the SpaceShips.

Comment: @Giovanni the drag chute debuted on the first flight of the newest Orbiter, Endeavour, STS-49. It was later retrofitted to the other Orbiters. https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/multimedia/imagegallery/Shuttle/EC92-05165-3.html

Comment: Note that according to Wikipedia, Virgin *have* at least at some point considered point-to-point revenue flights.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I know. They're planning to introduce the SpaceShipThree one day for that. But I wonder whether you could already do so with the SpaceShipOne and Two.